# How to test nulls using mockito?

Tags: flutter, testing, mocking, mockito, flutter-test

I am using [mockito 4.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) , and here I have some test class:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:ghinbli_app/models/film_model.dart';
import 'package:ghinbli_app/network/ghibli_films.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockClient extends Mock implements GhibliFilms {
  @override
  Future<List<FilmModel>> getFilms() async{
    return null;
  }
}

void main() {
  final GhibliFilms ghibliMock = MockClient();
  test('If API call was unsuccessful and data received is null', () {

    expect(ghibliMock.getFilms(), null);
  });
}
```

Inside the `MockClient` class, I am overriding a method called `getFilms()` and returning null to simulate a situation when a call to some API returns null as data.

---

### A problem

When I try to check if `getFilms()` actually returns a null value my test will fail with this error (probably because of the return type of `getFilms()`):

```
Expected: <null>
     Actual: <Instance of 'Future<List<FilmModel>>'>
```

---

How can I check and test that the data from `getFilms()` is actually null, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and got same error as you. After making these changes everything runs fine, try it yourself.

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements GhibliFilms {
  @override
  Future<List<FilmModel>> getFilms() async {
    return Future.value(null); // this is not that important
  }
}

void main() {
  final GhibliFilms ghibliMock = MockClient();

  // async/await here was important
  test('If API call was unsuccessful and data received is null', () async { 
    expect(await ghibliMock.getFilms(), null); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, btw I have checked it and you can simply return null in `getFilms` - no need for the Future.value.
I will soon mark your post as accepted
.